# how windbg determine which OS symbols to download for a dump file

Tags: debugging, windbg, symbols

When I do a dump file analysis, I setup symbol path to point to Microsoft symbol server. How does windbg knows that the dump file was generated under what OS and how does it downloads correct symbols for that OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match symbols to binary, WinDbg looks at the thing called Debug Directories. Debug Directories are sections in PE modules (which is a file format used by Windows for all types of executables). Debug Directories simply contain links to types of debug information. If you type command in cmd window `link /dump /headers <my_module_name>`, it will print out something like this:

```
...
Debug Directories

    Time Type       Size      RVA  Pointer
-------- ------ -------- -------- --------
4CC78FB1 cv           22 00102588   101988    Format: RSDS, {30976E0B-FBF7-45EF-8608-99932F2B791F}, 2, ntdll.pdb
4CC78FB1 (   A)        4 00102584   101984    BB03197E

...
```

This is output for ntdll.dll. You can see that CV (for CodeView) debug information is contained in  ntdll.pdb, and GUID of that PDB has to match the one in the link. That GUID is generated randomly for each module at build time.

Command `!lmi` in WinDbg will also dump this information, in different format.

What WinDbg does when loading symbols from symbol server is it sends request to symbol server to get file named 'ntdll.pdb' with matching GUID.

Comment: Do you mean this info is part of PE modules embeded within assemblies? When I create an application, I can run it over different OS with different Service packs. I am confused as to how this info stored in PE module can be used when application itself is running on different OS.

Comment: Each PE module has its own symbol file. There is no such thing as "symbols for OS", because OS is composed of a mixture of versions from different service packs, patches, hot fixes, private binaries, etc.

Comment: Let' say application assembly was compiled on Vista. I generate a dump for it on Windows 7 and another one for Windows Server 2008. In this case PE module will have Id for Vista, correct? How the two dump will get symbols for Windows 7 and 2008 in this case?

Comment: Again, there is no "OS symbols", there are symbols for particular PE module. Dump contains list of modules currently mapped to the process address space. There are different versions of kernel32.dll -- for different OS's processor architectures, more versions come with different OS patches. When debugger needs to resolve symbols for kernel32.dll, it looks up at the module information structure, which is created by the loader at the time module originally was loaded into process. This information contains some sections from PE image, including Debug Directory.